# Cant use 'fs' in my react-native project.. don't know how to solve

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fs

Hi im trying to use the fs.createReadStream() function in 'fs' however i cant seem to use this module as i keep getting this build error.

bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `fs` from file `/Users/bentait/Desktop/memriio/memriio_app/src/datapass.js`, the package `/Users/bentait/Desktop/memriio/memriio_app/node_modules/fs/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/bentait/Desktop/memriio/memriio_app/node_modules/fs/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

Im almost at my end trying to learn js, react, react-native.. i seem to spend 90% of time trying to solve these sorts of problems and 10% of time writing actual code..

anyway - not really expecting a response on this but cool, if you know how to help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not able to use node's `fs` because it is part of nodejs environment. As you surely know your application code is not running on nodejs but rather directly on your smartphone (besides debug mode but even there you cannot use node's `fs` package).

To access and manipulate smartphone's filesystem take a look at [react-native-fs](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) or [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) package.

Comment: Thanks Sebinq, Yes i didn't realize that fs was just for node.  i'll switch to to the packages you recommend here.