# @google-cloud/bigquery Unable to resolve module fs error

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, node.js-fs

I encountered this error when I tried to call this code from react-native client-side

```
    import { BigQuery } from "@google-cloud/bigquery";
    const name = "eminem";
    const age = 24;
    const data = {
      name: name,
      age: age,
    };
    
    const bigquery = new BigQuery();
// BigQuery API를 사용하여 데이터를 삽입합니다.
bigquery
  .insertAll({
    dataset: "<my_dataset>",
    table: "<my_table>",
    rows: [data],
    writeDisposition: "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
  })
  .then(() => {
    response.send({ status: "success", data: "Hello from Firebase!" });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    response.send({ status: "fail", data: "failed from firebase" });
  });





 ERROR  [Error: undefined Unable to resolve module fs from <my_node_modules_path>\node_modules\@google-cloud\bigquery\build\src\table.js: fs could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules\@google-cloud\bigquery\node_modules
  node_modules
  24 | const extend = require("extend");
  25 | const events_1 = require("events");
> 26 | const fs = require("fs");
     |                     ^
```

how can I do?
I've been searching the internet for a long time, but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: See the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027274/cant-use-fs-in-my-react-native-project-dont-know-how-to-solve

I believe that you are trying to use the Node JS @google-cloud/bigquery package which is for Node JS ... which is server side JavaScript and that is distinct from react-native which is browser app based code.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. if can't use @google-cloud/bigquery in react-native project, To use this, How can I do? I searched for official documentation, but can't get answer. I'll thank you for letting me know this.

Comment: Seems like the issue is related to the `fs` module. Can you take a look at these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046429/react-native-unable-to-resolve-module-fs) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71086804/).Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I believe what you want to do is invoke BigQuery APIs from JavaScript.  You can either form and send your own REST requests or leverage this pre-existing library ... https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client

Comment: Everybody thank you! I solved the problem. the problem is I invoked BigQuery API in client from react-native. it should be invoked In server. so I ran the function in server and solved the problem. Thank you everybody for commenting to me and sorry for this late answer. I forgot this page while doing other important things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @himaru mentioned in the comment:

*The error ‘Error: undefined Unable to resolve module fs’ was solved by running the function in the server. The problem occurred when invoked BigQuery API in the client from react-native and it was solved when invoked in the server.*

For more information and workaround refer to these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027274/cant-use-fs-in-my-react-native-project-dont-know-how-to-solve),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046429/react-native-unable-to-resolve-module-fs),[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71086804/) and [link4](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client).

Posting the answer as ***community wiki*** for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.